# react native fcm click_action when app is not running

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native

How to navigate to a page when notification is clicked, when app isn't running(not even in background).
I have the following code. But it doesn't catch my notificaation on click. I have seen implementation of click_action in native java code, but couldn't get any success in react native.

```
 this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {

      });
```

I am using [react native fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) package.
My payload looks like this

```
body = {
      to: reg_id,
      notification: {
        body: body,
        title: title,
        icon: icon,
        sound: 'default'
      }
    }.to_json
```

With this payload(i.e not passing the **click_action** in notification payload) my app opens, but **notificationListener** does not catch it and my app opens as  it would open normally.

And when i pass **click_action** like this

```
body = {
to: reg_id,
  notification: {
    body: body,
    title: title,
    icon: icon,
    sound: 'default',
    click_action: 'some click action'
  }
}.to_json
```

My app doesn't event opne normally. I read README of that package, but i couldn't understand it from there.

Any help will be very usesful.

Comment: Have you got any solution? @Akash